# New to snowflake and having issues loading JSON file into internal stage and then the table

Tags: json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, loading, snowflake-schema

I have a JSON file that I am trying to load via SnowSQL into Snowflake. I have an SQL script that's partially working. Here is a sample of the JSON file:

```
    {"year":"2011","_113_cause_name":"Nephritis, nephrotic syndrome and nephrosis (N00-     N07,N17-N19,N25-N27)","cause_name":"Kidney disease","state":"South Dakota","deaths":"49","aadr":"4.5"}
```

I have a series of SQL statements in a file that I then run fin SnowSQL CLI - see below:

```
enter code here

    /* create a table with variant column */
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CDC_SCHEMA.CDC_VAR
    (
       TEST_DATA VARIANT);
    /*create file format */
    create or replace file format CDC_DB.CDC_SCHEMA.sf_tut_csv_format
    field_delimiter = none
    record_delimiter = '\\n';

   create or replace temporary stage CDC_DB.CDC_SCHEMA.sf_tut_stage
   file_format = CDC_DB.CDC_SCHEMA.sf_tut_csv_format; 

   put file:///Users/rfrenkel/Downloads/LeadingCausesofDeath_noOA.json
   @CDC_DB.CDC_SCHEMA.sf_tut_stage; 

   copy into CDC_VAR
   from @CDC_DB.CDC_SCHEMA.sf_tut_stage/LeadingCausesofDeath_noOA.json.jz
   file_format = CDC_DB.CDC_SCHEMA.sf_tut_csv_format;

   SELECT * from CDC_VAR;
```

### When I run the SQL statements above - I get below output in the CLI:

| status                                       |
|----------------------------------------------|
| CDC_VAR already exists, statement succeeded. |
+----------------------------------------------+
1 Row(s) produced. Time Elapsed: 0.192s
+-----------------------------------------------------+
| status                                              |
|-----------------------------------------------------|
| File format SF_TUT_CSV_FORMAT successfully created. |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
1 Row(s) produced. Time Elapsed: 0.190s
+-----------------------------------------------+
| status                                        |
|-----------------------------------------------|
| Stage area SF_TUT_STAGE successfully created. |
+-----------------------------------------------+
1 Row(s) produced. Time Elapsed: 0.202s
LeadingCausesofDeath_noOA.json_c.gz(0.09MB): [##########] 100.00% Done (1.973s, 0.04MB/s).
+--------------------------------+-----------------------------------+-------------+-------------+--------------------+--------------------+----------+---------+
| source                         | target                            | source_size | target_size | source_compression | target_compression | status   | message |
|--------------------------------+-----------------------------------+-------------+-------------+--------------------+--------------------+----------+---------|
| LeadingCausesofDeath_noOA.json | LeadingCausesofDeath_noOA.json.gz |     1671572 |       91648 | NONE               | GZIP               | UPLOADED |         |
+--------------------------------+-----------------------------------+-------------+-------------+--------------------+--------------------+----------+---------+
1 Row(s) produced. Time Elapsed: 4.028s
+---------------------------------------+
| status                                |
|---------------------------------------|
| Copy executed with 0 files processed. |
+---------------------------------------+
1 Row(s) produced. Time Elapsed: 1.221s
+-----------+
| TEST_DATA |
|-----------|

It looks like COPY only produces one row in the CDC_VAR and I do not see any data when I look at it via the Graphical interface. I do not know what's wrong, and I am suspecting that the file format is incorrect. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you see this before you see the other post...

The file format on the stage table is delimited. You want to create a JSON file format and specify that instead.

Here is the code for the file format and the stage table.

```
create or replace file format CDC_DB.CDC_SCHEMA.JSON_FILE_FORMAT
TYPE = 'JSON'
COMPRESSION = 'AUTO' 
ENABLE_OCTAL = FALSE 
ALLOW_DUPLICATE = FALSE 
STRIP_OUTER_ARRAY = TRUE 
STRIP_NULL_VALUES = FALSE 
IGNORE_UTF8_ERRORS = FALSE;

create or replace stage CDC_DB.CDC_SCHEMA.sf_tut_stage
  file_format = CDC_DB.CDC_SCHEMA.JSON_FILE_FORMAT;
```